# SSRS - Cannot Export to PDF or Tiff but other formats work fine

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report.  The report runs fine both in BIDS and when I upload to the SSRS Server.  When I click to export to PDF or Tiff in BIDS, it just says Exporting Please Wait...  If I try to export to any format using the SSRS Server/Reports, it takes like 10 minutes, then comes back and says:

```
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>



Note: Runtime errors are enabled so this is the only error message I can get.  I went into the server logs on the SSRS server and this is what I can see that has errors:

library!ReportServer_0-2!804!07/01/2014-10:08:02:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
```

I have tried making a new report and copying over the items and it is still giving me the same problem so I really have no idea what to try next.  Please help!

Comment: Do you know how large the report is?  It could be the SSRS server is either running out of disk space or memory trying to save the report.

Comment: It is about 64 pages   Also, export to other formats works, its just PDF and TIFF that dont work.

Comment: @Razzle, if this is not what you mean by "how large the report is", can you tell me how to find this out?  I really need help and no one else seems to me trying to help me.

Comment: Off hand, the only thing I can think of is maybe your SSRS session timeout setting is not enough?  By default the timeout is set to 120 seconds.  It could be that the exporting to PDF and TIFF formats causes a timeout.

Comment: Are you using the Report Manager (versus the ReportViewer control on an ASP web form)? Does the report contain any charts or images? What fonts are you using? Looks like fonts other than Times New Roman, Arial, Courier, and Symbol need to be built and embedded in the PDF somehow by the SSRS PDF renderer. (Viewing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter... Thank you, Reflector.)

Comment: Also, what other applications or services are you running on the SSRS server/virtual machine? For example, are you running SQL Server and SSRS together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, but I did find the problem.  It seems the report was like 8.51 inches wide and didn't fit on a sheet.  For whatever reason, when I got it down to 8.5 including the margins, it seems to work now.  Stupid microsoft couldn't just give a reasonable error message.  Anyways, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this issue on timeouts really, this might not be helpful but have you tried running & accessing the report locally from your reporting services machine and seeing if it's someform of network issue. You shouldn't need any external PDF or Tiffing services installed on the PC for this to work. It may be that it'S more difficult to render PDF/Tiff than straight text to a file.